# Userscript to add a 'flag' button to deleted Stack Exchange posts

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange

As part of my daily routine, I flag deleted questions on Stack Exchange. Usually, I see something like this:

[image]

And to flag a deleted post that I can't see, I have to open [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and fake the POST request for flagging. This takes a lot of time and is inconvenient.

I want a userscript/extension that:

- Adds a flag button to deleted post 404 pages
- Ideally brings up the standard flag dialog, but it absolutely *must* allow me to input custom text for a 'requires moderator attention' flag. I don't really care about other flag types, so the standard dialog isn't required
- Ideally it wouldn't require me to authenticate with the API, instead using the standard POST requests available inside the page (with my fkey).

Is there a script that can do this?

Comment: Regarding your second bullet: the *only* flag option for deleted posts is "other".

Comment: Is that allowed? Is it the daily routine of all SE moderators? If so, why doesn't that functionality exist? How do you find a good reason for flagging if you can't see the content any more?

Comment: @ThomasW. It's allowed by the system, and it can be useful in a couple cases, primarily when you want to flag a *user* for something and their only content is deleted. It's not a daily routine for everyone, it's just a hobby I have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Flag Link for Deleted Messages
// @namespace    http://github.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Eh.
// @author       Madara Uchiha
// @include        /http:\/\/.+\.stackexchange.com/
// @include        /http:\/\/.+\.stackoverflow.com/
// @include        /http:\/\/stackoverflow.com/
// @include        /http:\/\/askubuntu.com/
// @include        /https:\/\/.+\.stackexchange.com/
// @include        /https:\/\/.+\.stackoverflow.com/
// @include        /https:\/\/stackoverflow.com/
// @include        /https:\/\/askubuntu.com/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

if ($('h1:contains(Page Not Found)').length > 0) {
    var postId = document.location.href.match(/questions\/(\d+)\//)[1];
    var $a = $('<a />', {
        text: 'Flag this question',
        css : {
            float: 'right'
        }
    });
    var $spinner = $('<img />', {
        src: 'http://i.imgur.com/YPmA6Jk.gif',
        css: {
            position: 'fixed',
            top     : 0,
            right   : 0
        }
    });
    $a.on('click', function () {
        var flagMessage = prompt('Enter flag message here.');
        $.post('/flags/posts/' + postId + '/add/PostOther', {
            fkey     : StackExchange.options.user.fkey,
            otherText: flagMessage
        }, hideSpinner);
        showSpinner()
    });
    $('#mainbar-full .subheader').append($a);
    $('#mainbar-full .subheader').append($spinner);

    $spinner.hide();

    function showSpinner() {
        $spinner.show();
    }

    function hideSpinner() {
        $spinner.hide('slow');
    }
}
```

Above userscript adds a link to the right of the header of every 404 page that allows you to flag the question with a custom flag via a simple `prompt()` call.

[image: Unicorns]

Comment: I've noticed that the userscript doesn't work (anymore?) in case the removed question is removed due to spam flags, while it does for deleted-but-not-as-spam posts.

Comment: Well, the test is for "Page Not Found" to be on the page (in an `<h1>` element). If that's different, then the userscript would indeed not work.